# Reference image not showing up?

Tags: image

I've seen tons of other posts on this, but they don't help. I'm following a certain Youtuber's tutorial on modeling, and he uses a reference image of a mug to help him model his mug, so I decided to do the same. Thing is, it's not showing up, even when I go into Front/Side/Top Ortho view. Here:[image]

EDIT:

[.blend file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/qymqhmuoysn47ui/donut.blend1/file)

[Reference Image](http://www.mediafire.com/view/iw4k06zqe2v4ipe/vardera-mug-white__51249_PE150726_S4.jpg)

Comment: @CytaStorm, could you please share your image file + blender file?

Comment: ...at the least a picture of image open in image editor (to ensure it is not a broken path) . By the looks it has a relative path (filename starts with //) indicating image file  should be in same folder as blend file. There are some tools under _`File > External Data`_ menu to report and find missing files (If this is the case)

Answer (score 2):

Your image is not a JPG file...it's a WebP file, which Blender does not seem to be able to load as a background image.  Try a different image.   I took a screenshot of the image from my web browser, so you should be able to download and use this one:

[image]

Comment: Other common files seem to work, too. I've tested PNG myself.

Comment: It is a JPG file though.

Comment: it has a .jpg extension, but it is NOT a jpg file.  If you open it with a hex editor you'll see it's a RIFF container that holds a WebP format.   I can't even open the file with an image editor.  I also downloaded the exact file from the IKEA website using Chrome, and it saves it with a .jpg extension but it's not a JPEG formatted file.

Comment: using the 'file' command on Linux gives: `RIFF (little-endian) data, Web/P image, VP8 encoding
, 500x500, Scaling: [none]x[none], YUV color, decoders should clamp`

Comment: a JPG file should give something like: `JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 72x72, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1322x1053, frames 3`